# How can I post google blooger without a limit?

Tags: python, oauth, limit, blogs, credentials

I'm a google blooger.
I upload 10 posts everyday by using python.
After uploaded 25 posts, I have to make a new credential.

This is code

```
CLIENT_SECRET = 'client_secret.json'
SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger'
STORAGE = Storage('credentials.storage')
# Start the OAuth flow to retrieve credentials
def authorize_credentials():
# Fetch credentials from storage
    credentials = STORAGE.get()
# If the credentials doesn't exist in the storage location then run the flow
    if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
        flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET, scope=SCOPE)
        http = httplib2.Http()
        credentials = run_flow(flow, STORAGE, http=http)
    return credentials
credentials = authorize_credentials()
```

Do you have an idea there is any method without refreshing credential by mannual?

Comment: what do you see in credentials.storage file? is there a refresh token?   Is your project on google cloud console set to testing?

Answer (score 0):

My python isnt the best but i think you might have an indentation issue.  Have a look at this.

```
def initialize_blogger():
  """Initializes the blogger service object.

  Returns:
    analytics an authorized blogger service object.
  """
  # Parse command-line arguments.
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
      formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
      parents=[tools.argparser])
  flags = parser.parse_args([])

  # Set up a Flow object to be used if we need to authenticate.
  flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
      CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH, scope=SCOPES,
      message=tools.message_if_missing(CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH))

  # Prepare credentials, and authorize HTTP object with them.
  # If the credentials don't exist or are invalid run through the native client
  # flow. The Storage object will ensure that if successful the good
  # credentials will get written back to a file.
  storage = file.Storage('blogger.dat')
  credentials = storage.get()
  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
  http = credentials.authorize(http=httplib2.Http())

  # Build the service object.
  service= build('blogger', 'v3', http=http)

  return service
```